# PHP websocket disconnects automatically

Tags: php, websocket, phpwebsocket

I am using websocket functionality for my project for messaging purpose. I am using PHP websocket which I have downloaded from following link
 https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat . But my problem is my web socket automatically gets disconnected for some time and it again reconnects automatically. Because of this my messages are getting lost. So can anybody tell me how I can resolve this issue. Is there any modification in code that I can do so that I can overcome this problem. Thank you.

Following is my server.php file

```
    <?php
// prevent the server from timing out
set_time_limit(0);

// include the web sockets server script (the server is started at the far bottom of this file)
require 'class.PHPWebSocket.php';

// when a client sends data to the server
function wsOnMessage($clientID, $message, $messageLength, $binary) {
global $Server;
$ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

// check if message length is 0
if ($messageLength == 0) {
$Server->wsClose($clientID);
return;
}

//The speaker is the only person in the room. Don't let them feel lonely.
if ( sizeof($Server->wsClients) == 1 )
$Server->wsSend($clientID, "There isn't anyone else in the room, but I'll still listen to you. --Your Trusty Server");
else
//Send the message to everyone but the person who said it
foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
if ( $id != $clientID )
$Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) said \"$message\"");
}

// when a client connects
function wsOnOpen($clientID)
{
global $Server;
$ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

$Server->log( "$ip ($clientID) has connected." );

//Send a join notice to everyone but the person who joined
foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
if ( $id != $clientID )
$Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) has joined the room.");
}

// when a client closes or lost connection
function wsOnClose($clientID, $status) {
global $Server;
$ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

$Server->log( "$ip ($clientID) has disconnected." );

//Send a user left notice to everyone in the room
foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
$Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) has left the room.");
}

// start the server
$Server = new PHPWebSocket();
$Server->bind('message', 'wsOnMessage');
$Server->bind('open', 'wsOnOpen');
$Server->bind('close', 'wsOnClose');
// for other computers to connect, you will probably need to change this to your LAN IP or external IP,
// alternatively use: gethostbyaddr(gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))
$Server->wsStartServer('127.0.0.1', 9300);

?>
```

And javascript code is

```
    var FancyWebSocket = function(url)
{
var callbacks = {};
var ws_url = url;
var conn;

this.bind = function(event_name, callback){
callbacks[event_name] = callbacks[event_name] || [];
callbacks[event_name].push(callback);
return this;// chainable
};

this.send = function(event_name, event_data){
this.conn.send( event_data );
return this;
};

this.connect = function() {
if ( typeof(MozWebSocket) == 'function' )
this.conn = new MozWebSocket(url);
else
this.conn = new WebSocket(url);

// dispatch to the right handlers
this.conn.onmessage = function(evt){
dispatch('message', evt.data);
};

this.conn.onclose = function(){dispatch('close',null)}
this.conn.onopen = function(){dispatch('open',null)}
};

this.disconnect = function() {
this.conn.close();
};

var dispatch = function(event_name, message){
var chain = callbacks[event_name];
if(typeof chain == 'undefined') return; // no callbacks for this event
for(var i = 0; i < chain.length; i++){
chain[i]( message )
}
}
};
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using.

Comment: I Patrik thanks for you reply. You can get code form above link < https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat >.

Comment: No, thats where you downloaded it from, we need the code that you are actually using. We cant help you with a problem you are having unless we see the code you are actually using. And only the relevant parts.

Comment: Hi Patrik can you please check the code.

Comment: and the javascript code?

Comment: Patrik I have posted js code too.

Comment: @user2260521 I have same problem ? Please let me know if you got solution.

Answer (score 2):

my guess is that the socket class is not handling pings/pongs correctly. I've used that socket script before and recall having the same issue.

Try https://github.com/lemmingzshadow/php-websocket and see if it's a better starting point. It's more complicated if your just trying to figure out websocket service programming in PHP, but it's a better place to start either way.

Comment: Hi! thanks for you reply, but can you tell me the reliability of this web socket i.e. does it gives any acknowledgement when message is received or at least log the instances when websocket disconnects.

Comment: @user2260521 - I can't comment on on how reliable it is because I haven't used it as a production service, but I used it along with a few others to compair performance against a websocket service that I'm building for PHP using Boost.Asio. I hit it millions of times times in a echo test and it didn't crash or behave outside of what I expected. I don't think it logged to a file, but it had extensive console logging that can probably be caught using an output buffer and written to a file.